# Does Fourier Transform Convention Change Convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, fast-fourier-transform, step-function

My goal is to find the Fourier transform of the product of two functions: The Heaviside step function $\theta(t)$, and $g(t) = A - A\cos(\omega_0 t)$. I want to do this by *first* Fourier transforming $\theta$ and $g$, and then convolving the results.

I used the Fourier transform convention

$$
F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t) e^{i \omega t} dt \qquad \qquad 
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(\omega)e^{-i \omega t} d\omega
$$

to find that the frequency domain representations to be 
$$
\Theta(\omega) = \frac{i}{\omega} + \pi \delta(\omega), \quad \mathrm{and} \quad G(\omega) = 2\pi A\left(\delta(\omega) -\frac{\delta(\omega-\omega_0)}{2}-\frac{\delta(\omega+\omega_0)}{2}\right).
$$

So, now I need to convolve the results. Based on sources such as [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html), 
$$
\Theta(\omega)*G(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Theta(x)G(\omega-x)dx
$$
should do the trick. The problem is that after repeated attempts, I always get an answer that is a factor of $2\pi$ larger than what I think it should be physically. This makes me suspicious:
**Is my definition of convolution correct, or do I need to somehow modify it to account for the different Fourier transform convention?** (In other words, does the convolution integral change with different Fourier transform conventions, and if so, what should I use for my convention?)

---

**Sidenote: Is this approach valid?**

@Ninad Munshi writes:
"It's not your definition of convolution that is the problem. Your assumption that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms is incorrect with this convention"

Note the following line at the bottom of page 98 in [Stanford Prof. Brad Osgood's reader](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf):
$$
\mathcal{F}(gf) = \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(k * h)^{-}) = k * h = \mathcal{F}g * \mathcal{F}f
$$
where $h = \mathcal{F}f$ and $k = \mathcal{F} g$. A proof is provided in the reference linked above. **As you can easily see, the Fourier transform of the product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms,** which is in contrast to the comment by @Math1000.

Can someone please explain to me either (1) what is meant by @Ninad Munshi and @Math1000, or (2) where the factor of $2\pi$ comes from? I have a guess that the duality operation changing with F.T. convention may be the culprit. Note the added factor of $2\pi$ in the ["Duality" section of this page](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Xforms/FXProps.html##section6) (you'll need to ctrl+f).

Comment: It's not your definition of convolution that is the problem. Your assumption that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms is incorrect with this convention.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Woah -- really? Is there only one convention for which this convolution integral works?

Comment: No that's not the issue either. Why don't you try deriving the property and see what happens.

Comment: Convolution in the time domain corresponds to multiplication in the frequency domain. This does not mean that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms.

Comment: @Math1000 right, so obviously taking the product of $\theta$ and $g$, and then Fourier transforming them would work, but I need to do it the other way. How do I properly Fourier transform a product if I need to do the Fourier transforming step first?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other method that would be easier.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Does this new "sidenote" get at your question?

Comment: @Math1000 I found a source that seems to show that, "the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms." Am I missing something?

Comment: "Multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain" - makes sense. What I wrote wasn't wrong, it's just that this doesn't follow from the more commonly known statement that I wrote without additional argument (which your source provides). As far as I can tell you are correct. The extra factor of $2\pi$ probably comes from the definition of Fourier transform you are using. That is my guess, at least.